# How would this binary-ish code be translated?

Tags: mathematics, cipher

```
10101010101001 01 010100010 010 10 01010 010101.. 1001010
10 0100 00 0 100 01001010100101010 0101 01010 01 010 100 0
1010010 010010 0 011  101  10 1 01 10 0 01 01 01 01 010 01 010
10010 01 01 01 01001000 10 01 0010110111111100 0 0 001 10 0
```

This is the exact source of what it's supposed to be, spaces and all. Apparently it's not binary (or at least, not ASCII text converted to binary).

And that's all I know really. It's supposed to be simple and it's a "code" you have to "crack", and the person who gave me this puzzle is really good at mathematics.

Any help?

EDIT: "...there is a phrase in mind and a way to decode it but the way to get to the phrase does extend outside the realm of just decoding the numbers themselves."

Comment: Well, there are two suspension dots there, so it's not encoding punctuation. Also, bc of that, it doesn't seem to be something about spacing (otherwise why having the dots?). It doesn't look like morse either. The token "01" is repeated very often alone. Is the double space between 011 and 101  and 10 intentional or a mistake?

Comment: Reminds me of the `0 10 1011 1031 102113 10311213 ...` sequence. That would match "easy". Wait, it starts with 1. http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/2271/interview-question-or-pathbreaking-puzzle