# What is the next in the sequence?

Tags: riddle, cipher

Fill in the blanks for each sequence:

1) ottffssentettff _ _ _ _ _

2) J A S O N _ _ _

3)

1
11
21
1211
111221
312211
?

Comment: Pretty sure nr 1 and 3 are duplicates here. No time to look them up though.

Comment: 3) is the Nth duplicate of https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/2271/32339

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1)

> ssent
> (First letters of next numbers in series.)

2)

> D J F
>  (First letters of next months in series.)

3)

> 13112221
>  (A "description" of the line above it, numerically.)