# Simple Number Puzzle

Tags: riddle, pattern

This puzzle should be easy to solve if you don't overthink.

> 1,
>    11,
>    21,
>    1211,
>    111221,
>    ???

What's the next number?

Comment: Hello and welcome to PSE. As you are definitely not the author of this sequence you should really post where you got it from. Most of the popular number sequences are listed in OEIS at https://oeis.org/

Comment: Also, this has already appeared several times on this site, see for example: https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/2271/interview-question-or-pathbreaking-puzzle

Comment: Actually sombody showed me this riddle a long time ago i have no idea oeis.org exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1, 11, 21, 1211, 111221, 312211, 13112221, 1113213211
>
>  sequence A005150 from OEIS  https://oeis.org/A005150