# Secret Communications

Tags: pattern, story

Hopefully this pattern isn't a repeat of any puzzle posted previously...

> Dawn, Dec 17 XXXX
>
> "Our future is in your hands. I wish you the best of luck."
>
> With that, the hooded man lays before you a scrap of dirty paper and exits the room. Peering at the sheet under dim lamplight, you notice the imperial seal of Country Y and the word 'CONFIDENTIAL' printed in block letters. Your stomach tightens in anticipation--the agents had succeeded.
>
> Somehow, they had obtained the communications cipher for the enemy's upcoming attack, and now they require the assistance of the nations greatest code breaker to usher in victory!
>
> The paper reads:
>
> Dec 13 XXXX -> 223
>   Dec 14 XXXX -> 2213
>   Dec 15 XXXX -> 221113
>   Dec 16 XXXX -> 223113
>
> What is the communications password for Dec 17 XXXX?

Answer (score 2):

The communications password for December 17th, XXXX is

> **22132113**, following the [look-and-say sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Look-and-say_sequence).

If this is actually the intended answer, I'm almost sure that [this is a duplicate](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/2271/interview-question-or-pathbreaking-puzzle).