# Find the next number in the sequence 911, 1921,

Tags: pattern, number-sequence

The sequence is as follows:

> 911, 1921, 11191211, 3119111221.

Tell me the next number in the sequence and what the pattern is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The next number is

> 132119312211

And the pattern is

> The famous '[say what you see pattern](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/2271/interview-question-or-pathbreaking-puzzle)' - usually done with 1s and 2s - so in the first number, there is one 9 and two ones, so the second number is 1921

Comment: I was just about to post

Comment: rot13(Yrg'f erzrzore Wbua Ubegba Pbajnl, jub vairfgvtngrq guvf frdhrapr dhvgr gubebhtuyl.)

Answer (score 3):

The next number in the series should be:

> 132119312211

The pattern is:

> A given number in the sequence, n, describes the previous number in the sequence, n - 1. For example: 1921 describes 911 because there is **one** 9 and **two** 1s.

Comment: You got the right answer and your explanation is correct, but Beastly Gerbil got the explanation spot on. Still, well done!