# Non-mathematical number sequence

Tags: pattern, number-sequence

Side question.
I think I have never seen this sequence after my father posed the problem to me decennia ago. So apart from the solution, I would like to know if someone has seen it before.

Note: Below the problems in its hardest, somewhat hidden form.

The challenge, for good old times:

Find the next entry in this sequence starting with 1:

111211211111221312211131122211113213211

Some little help:

> The start of the sequence starting with 4 for some additional data to analyse:
>  414111431141321141113122114311311222114

Comment: It's a very famous problem thats been posted here many many times. [It was first posted here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/2271/interview-question-or-pathbreaking-puzzle)

Comment: Guess I have to get some 'find duplicate' skills. (thx)

Comment: @Retudin Remembered this answer on my question:https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6954/70593